# Chef cookbook with log_level set to :debug: Do not echo binary files

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to debug a chef cookbook, and there are a bunch of files being copied via the following:

```
remote_directory "/var/www/html/assets" do
  source 'assets'
  files_owner user
  files_group user
  files_mode '0755'
  action :create
  recursive true
  sensitive true
end
```

Some of those files are binary.  When `log_level` is set to `:warn`, everything is fine, but when `log_level` is set to `:debug`, the binaries are echoed back to the console.  This behavior then wreaks havoc with the terminal (using `chef_client`, if it matters).  As a consequence, the output has to be redirected to a file, but the redirected output is many megabytes long, which makes the debugging more cumbersome.

Is there a way to suppress the output?  I'm looking for some solution like

```
  sensitive :DO_NOT_ECHO_AND_I_MEAN_IT_DAMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

chef ecosystem is not a deployment tool, but rather a configuration management. there is no point to store binary data within your source control management, binary data needs to be produced by compiling your repository code and create a package, which you will deliver by deploying it to the node.

with that being said and if you still want to use chef for the deployment task, then here are couple of ideas:

1. use [`git` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html) and clone a repository into a desired location (might have some security concerns)
2. store your package file (an archive file containing all the binary files and such packed) on http server, then use [`http_request` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_http_request.html) in conjunction with [`tar` resource](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/tar) to download the package file and extract it

of course your can find many other ways to do so, but i think you got the hint :)

Comment: The docs for cookbook_file specifically describe atomic update of a binary file.  For example (search for binary):  https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html

Comment: as you said, this is an example and not the best practices i have noted you in my post. you can always do it your way... :)